# Estou aprendendo Python e tem um exercício usando o FOR que não estou conseguindo fazer, alguem pode me ajudar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, for, while

1. Construa uma algoritmo que leia a idade e sexo de 5 pessoas, fornecendo:

*A quantidade de homens e mulheres;

*A média da idade dos homens e mulheres;

*A maior idade entre os homens;

*A menor idade entre as mulheres.

---

Esse exercício foi de uma atividade em C# ai eu quero aplicar em python

Comment: Veja [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pensei em fazer assim, python é bem flexivel, pode ser feito de varias  maneiras.

```
homens_sexo = []
homens_idade = []
mulheres_sexo = []
mulheres_idade = []

for item in range(5):
    print('\n-- Pesquisa --')
    sexo = input('\nSexo(M | F): ')
    idade = int(input('Qual sua idade: '))
    if sexo in 'mM':
        homens_sexo.append(sexo)
        homens_idade.append(idade)
    else:
        mulheres_sexo.append(sexo)
        mulheres_idade.append(idade)

# *A quantidade de homens e mulheres;
print("*"*35)
print('\nResultado final da pesquisa\n')
print(f'\n\nQuantidade de Homens: {len(homens_sexo)}')
print(f'\nQuantidade de Mulheres: {len(mulheres_sexo)}')

# *A média da idade dos homens e mulheres;
print(f'\nMédia de idade dos Homens: {sum(homens_idade) / len(homens_idade)}')
print(f'\nMédia de idade das Mulheres: {sum(mulheres_idade) / len(mulheres_idade)}')

# *A maior idade entre os homens;
print(f'\nMaior idade entre os Homens: {max(homens_idade)}')

# *A menor idade entre as mulheres.
print(f'\nMaior idade entre as Mulheres: {min(mulheres_idade)}')
```

Answer (score -1):

Pensei em fazer dessa maneira, veja se te ajuda:

```
print('ler idade e sexo de 5 pessoas')

sexo = []
idade = []
soma_m = 0
soma_f = 0
cont_m = 0
cont_f = 0
idade_m = []
idade_f = []

for x in range(5):
    sexo.append(input("Entre com o sexo (digite m ou f): "))
    idade.append(input("Agora a idade: "))


print ("O número total de homens: %d" % sexo.count('m'))
print ("O número total de mulheres: %d" % sexo.count('f'))

for x in range(5):
    if sexo[x] == 'm':
        soma_m = soma_m + int(idade[x])
        idade_m.append(int(idade[x]))
        cont_m = cont_m + 1
    if sexo[x] == 'f':
        soma_f = soma_f + int(idade[x])
        cont_f = cont_f + 1
        idade_f.append(int(idade[x]))

print("A média da idade dos homens é: %.2f" % (soma_m / cont_m) )
print("A média da idade das mulheres é: %.2f" % (soma_f / cont_f) )

print("A maior idade do grupo de homens: %d " % max(idade_m))
print("A maior idade do grupo de mulheres %d " % min(idade_f))
```